# Как получать только одно значение после парсинга в python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, словарь

Я изучаю requests запросы в python. Используя метод post я решил спарсить неиросеть Порфирьевич и позже добавить ее в телеграм бота. Всё благополучно спарсилось, но дело в том что он получает в качестве ответа ключ replies и значения к нему в виде текста.
Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
import requests
import json


prompt = input('Введи начало истории, а я продолжу: ')

data = {'prompt': prompt}

r = requests.post(f'https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/', json=data)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json()['replies'])
```

После выполнения выводит:

```
Введи начало истории, а я продолжу: Привет

200

[', Карл. Что ты хотел?', ' у меня есть друг – Курчатов Александр Львович – уже старенький.', ', господин! – тут же поздоровался Фреди.']
```

Насколько я понимаю он выдаёт сразу несколько запросов на слово привет. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы он выдавал только один value после запроса и был в формате текста после доставания из словаря? То есть `Карл, Что ты хотел?` и ничего лишнего без `[]` и без `''` .
Я пробовал пользоваться стандартными методами .values() итд. , но в ответ всегда получал словарь с перечислением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это же обычный питоновский список. Можете взять любой его элемент, например первый:

```py
print(r.json()['replies'][0])
```

А можете перебрать все элементы списка:

```py
for text in r.json()['replies']:
    print(text)
```

Пример вывода:

```
 с петушком! Пусть быстрее приходит!
, Билл, как ты? В порядке?
, Рэнди, меня зовут Виктор.
```

Comment: Благодарю, все оказалось куда проще чем я думал.

Comment: @Alex Ну да, главное понять какой тип данных перед вами, дальше всё стандартно. Тип можно проверить с помощью функции `type()`